# TFS 2010 enforcing Code Analysis in Gated Checkins

Tags: tfs

Is it possible to enforce VS Code Analysis (FxCop) as part of the Gated Checkin policies?
So the developers will not be able to checkin unless the CA is passed.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes this is possible. Please see the following:

> [How to: Add Check-in Policies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181459(VS.80).aspx)